# Sometimes I see this character � in my web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor, utf-8, character-encoding

Sometimes I see this character � near a Persian character in some pages and in my dynamic sitemap url.

I have tried:

- list below metatag,
- save all the pages with unicode utf-8 code page 65001

How can I prevent this character being shown?

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="fa" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this character? Did you try to pinpoint the stage at which that character pops out? In other words, (1) are you sure that such a character is not literally present in your text as a result of some previous encoding conversion? and (2) are you sure that it is not just your webbrowser or fonts installed on a particular machine the one to blame?

Comment: These characters appear instead of one  or two letter in the word  inside paragraph ,And it could happen anywhere in the page and I changed the font, but I still saw these characters, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you change codepage at round trip requests ?
i had a problem like this ,because me change codepage in round trip requests .

Comment: Thanks alot Mr.Mohammadi ,I've solved my problem with your help.
 bad implementation CDN and change CodePage in global.asx Caused This problem , The problem was fixed by modifying the code